# How to determine stationarity, mean and covariance?

Tags: time-series, self-study, mean, covariance, stationarity

I'm having some trouble with some questions for an assignment that I need to do.

The question asks to determine whether or not a process is stationary and if it is, what is its mean and covariance. The usually assumptions apply: $e_{t}$ is a white noise process with variance $\sigma^2$ and $a$, $b$, $c$ are constants. Also, "stationary" refers to *weakly stationary*.

One of the processes is: $X_{t} = e_{1}\cos(ct) + e_{t-1}\sin(ct)$.

I'm just looking for some help on how to approach this problem, a method if you will, not the answer.

Comment: You may want to add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Is this a discrete-time process or a continuous-time process? Can you apply the _linearity of expectation_ to figure out what $E[X_t] = E[e_t \cos(ct) + e_{t-1}\sin(ct)]$  is for a given fixed number $t$? What about $E[X_{t_1}X_{t_2}]$ after applying FOIL followed by the linearity of expectation? Does anything in the question suggest what the value of $E[e_te_{t-1}]$ might be?